# JBoss Developer Studio turn on syntax highlighting for freemarker template files

Tags: eclipse, jboss, freemarker

Is there a way to turn on syntax highlighting for Freemarker Template files (.ftl) in JBoss Developer Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ Ultimate has Freemarker Template syntax highlighting.  It costs $599.

Answer (score 1):

With JBDS 3.0 you should have Freemarker Template syntax highlighting by default.  If you're using eclipse the community version of JBoss Tools also includes this feature.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the settings at JBoss Developer Studio -> Preferences -> FreeMarker Editor

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the party, but you may also want to try the Scipio ERP plugin. It has its own Freemarker implementation and even supports the community edition.